# Is it possible to turn on Authentication in empty ASP.NET Core Mvc project?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm stuck in authentication in my project. I created asp.net mvc project without authentication. I have existing database. I added db by executing: `Scaffold-Dbcontext` and use this in Startup.cs(ConfigureServices method):

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDb")));
```

For Identity i added this in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and this in Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I have next controller:

```
 private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly AppContext _context;
        public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, AppContext context)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._signInManager = signInManager;
            _context = context;
        }
```

And when i try to find user by id:
`var usr = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);` App throw this exception :`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'`
Change inherit in context to IdentityDbContext throw 3 new exceptions, one of them is :

```
'App.Chat.Identity.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'App.Chat.Identity.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.
```

Can someone explain how to use authentication in empty project? Or i need to recreate project with individual auth? (Second varian will hurt me).

**Edit #1**
Here is additional info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace App.Chat.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

And startup info:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDb")));
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Edit #2**
My AppContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using App.Chat.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace App.Chat.TModels
{
    public partial class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
    : base(options)
        { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser` which is not a ASP.NET Core package. It's for the old framework.

Check your nuget packages and uninstall `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`

Comment: 'The type 'App.Chat.TModels.AppContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>(IdentityBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'App.Chat.TModels.AppContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.'

Comment: You should be getting close. In Startup under Configure you probably also need  app.UseAuthentication(); Why don't you create a new project webapplication and Change Authentication to Store User accounts in app. Then you compare Startup add take what you are missing.

Comment: @ivw, i used it "app.UseAuthentication(); "

Comment: How do you implement you DbContext? Like this?

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

Comment: What is your DbContext class name? `ApplicationDbContext` or `AppContext`? in code you wrote `AppContext`. if it's `ApplicationDbContext` change the name and see if it works

Comment: @Kahbazi, yep, it's works. but i got new exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.'`

Comment: @qwiz That's whole another question, You should ask a new question and write the code for `IdentityUserLogin`

Answer (score 1):

Like Kahbazi suggested change name. And check these 2 classes.

```
 //change in startup.
//services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

 public class HomeController
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._signInManager = signInManager;
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, it's works. but i got new exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.'`

Comment: Yes we forgot to change to homecontroller to use ApplicationDbContext, I added it.

Comment: Drop database and let it be recreated. AppContext if it created you db before won't have it, but now with your new code it is mentioned in ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs 193).

Comment: drop database, did you mean delete all models and again use scaffold-dbcontext? I can't understand

Comment: Depends on your connectionstring.  Is it localbd find the file and delete. for example  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication2-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169343/discussion-between-ivw-and-qwiz).

Comment: for .net core you can drop db like this. > dotnet ef database drop